# Javascript function not working for all elements

Tags: javascript, html, image, src

I'm trying to write a script which changes image on mouse hover. I have 6 images, but the function is working for only one of them (the first one)

```
<div id="picture-container">
    <img class="picture" id="360" src="360.jpg" onclick="enlarge(360);"  onmouseover="pic_info(360);"
    onmouseout="pic_ret(360);"/>
    <img class="picture" id="bmx" src="bmx.jpg" onclick="enlarge(bmx);"/>
    <img class="picture" id="buzludzha" src="buzludzha.jpg" onclick="enlarge(buzludzha);"
    onmouseover="pic_info(buzludzha);"/>
    <img class="picture" id="pirata" src="pirata.jpg" onclick="enlarge(pirata);"
    onmouseover="pic_info(pirata);"/>
    <img class="picture" id="snowboard" src="snowboard.jpg" onclick="enlarge(snowboard);"
    onmouseover="pic_info(snowboard);"/>
    <img class="picture" id="vitiskali" src="vitiskali.jpg" onclick="enlarge(vitiskali);"
    onmouseover="pic_info(vitiskali);"/>
    <img class="picture" id="ispolin" src="ispolin.jpg" onclick="enlarge(ispolin);"
    onmouseover="pic_info(ispolin);"/>

</div>
```

And the script:

```
function pic_info(id) {

if (id == "360") {
    var p = document.getElementById(id);
    p.src = "360info.jpg";
}
if (id == "buzludzha") {
    var p = document.getElementById(id);
    p.src = "buzludzhainfo.jpg";
}
if (id == "pirata") {
    var p = document.getElementById(id);
    p.src = "piratainfo.jpg";
}
if (id == "snowboard") {
    var p = document.getElementById(id);
    p.src = "snowboardinfo.jpg";
}
if (id == "vitiskali") {
    var p = document.getElementById(id);
    p.src = "vitiskaliinfo.jpg";
}
if (id == "ispolin") {
    var p = document.getElementById(id);
    p.src = "ispolininfo.jpg";
}
```

As I said the script works only for picture with id="360" and it is imported in the head tag of the html document.The same thing happens with the function "enlarge();". Why is that and how can I fix it?
Thank you, in advance!

Comment: Can I suggest a rewrite of your code? Something along the lines of: `function pic_info(id){var p = document.getElementById(id); var src = id + "info.jpg"; p.src = src; }`, much easier to read and extend to new functionality.

Comment: Not exactly related, but a single `var p = document.getElementById(id);` would had been enough, you don't need six of them ...

Comment: drop those if statements ... use a switch statement instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Answer (score 7):

just to scratch the surface, are passing a variable instead of a string : `enlarge(bmx);` should be : `enlarge('bmx');`, and so on for the others